# Trying to print from a 3D array by joining variable names and printing only one column

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array

```
jEngines = [
            [["Aerotech 54mm Motor (J1799N)"], ["0.6"], ["1799"], ["1090"], ["540"]],
            [["Cesaroni 54mm Motor (J760)"], ["1.7"], ["760"], ["1076"], ["576"]],
            [["Aerotech 54mm Motor (J401FJ)"], ["2.8"], ["401"], ["912"], ["511"]],
            [["Aerotech 54mm Motor (J800T)"], ["1.6"], ["800"], ["1134"], ["595"]],
            [["Aerotech 38mm Motor (J825R)"], ["1.2"], ["825"], ["878"], ["497"]],
            [["Cesaroni 38mm Motor (J94)"], ["6.8"], ["94"], ["660"], ["372"]],
            [["Aerotech 38mm Motor (J425R)"], ["1.6"], ["425"], ["631"], ["364"]],
            [["Aerotech 38mm Motor (J500G)"], ["1.4"], ["500"], ["654"], ["375"]],
            [["Aerotech 38mm Motor (J420)"], ["1.6"], ["420"], ["635"], ["345"]],
            [["Aerotech 38mm Motor (J340M)"], ["1.8"], ["340"], ["577"], ["365"]]
            ]
kEngines = [
            [["Aerotech 54mm Motor (K456DM)"], ["2.9"], ["456"], ["1484"], ["866"]],
            [["Aerotech 54mm Motor (K2050ST)"], ["0.7"], ["2050"], ["2086"], ["1292"]],
            [["Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K300)"], ["8.4"], ["300"], ["2270"], ["1265"]],
            [["Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K260)"], ["8.7"], ["260"], ["2047"], ["1149"]],
            [["Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K1200)"], ["1.7"], ["1200"], ["1631"], ["960"]],
            [["Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K2045)"], ["0.7"], ["2045"], ["1290"], ["716"]],
            [["Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K940)"], ["1.8"], ["940"], ["1366"], ["768"]],
            [["Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K630)"], ["2.7"], ["630"], ["1410"], ["912"]]
            ]
def heightPrint():
    rEngine = input("Pick a class of engine a-l (lowercase):")
    rEngine= rEngine+("Engines")
    print("You have chosen class {}".format(rEngine))
    print("These are the engines in class {}".format(rEngine))
    for x in range 20:
        print(eval(rEngine[0][x]))
```

Above is a segment of the 3D array and problem I am trying to solve. This is probably a very messy way of doing it but I want to be able to print the Engines from the array with /n after each one but it doesn't like having square brackets after the eval line and does not like having a str in the square brackets too.

Comment: 20 was given as an example as I am unsure on how to have this go to the length of a column in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** Using `eval()` is bad practice as I learned. If you are the only person to ever use this, the solution below is fine, but if other people will access this tool, this approach is dangerous, as inputting `print(1)#` will make the program print a 1 with all the implications that come with it. The code can be fixed by checking that the input character is within a range of allowed inputs after receiving the input

```py
if rEngine not in ['k', 'j']:
    break # or do whatever action is needed, like prompting the user again
```

The "pythonic" way to go about this, though, would be a dictionary mapping the names to the arrays and getting the array that way

```py
engines = {'jEngines': jEngines, 'kEngines': kEngines}
rEngine = engines[rEngine]
```

---

You could `eval()` the engine before you are going to access it and access it as an array after

```
def heightPrint():
    rEngine = input("Pick a class of engine a-l (lowercase): ")
    rEngine = rEngine+"Engines"
    print("These are the engines in class {}".format(rEngine))
    print("You have chosen class {}".format(rEngine))
    rEngine = eval(rEngine)
    for x in rEngine:
        print(x[0][0])
```

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to print, this function will get you the name "Aerotech 54mm Motor (J1799N)" and so on.

For `kEngines` as in your post, the function would result in the following output:

```py
heightPrint()

Pick a class of engine a-l (lowercase): k
You have chosen class kEngines
These are the engines in class kEngines
Aerotech 54mm Motor (K456DM)
Aerotech 54mm Motor (K2050ST)
Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K300)
Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K260)
Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K1200)
Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K2045)
Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K940)
Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K630)
```

Comment: So I am trying to get it to print the engines from the array for the engine type selected for example: Aerotech 54mm Motor (K456DM) Aerotech 54mm Motor (K2050ST), Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K300), Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K260), Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K1200), Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K2045), Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K940), Cesaroni 54mm Motor (K630)

Comment: E.g: print(eval(rEngine[row[0] for row in rEngine)) but it doesn't like this. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried my code snippet at all? Printing the engine names is literally what it does ;) I'll edit the post to include an example

Comment: It was giving me an error when I tried it before but have since managed to get it to work, thanks.